# What is the complexity of a variation of the Coupon collector's problem?

Tags: time-complexity, probability-theory

I need to know the complexity of the following algorithm:

Draw elements from a set of size $m$, one by one, randomly, with replacement, until coming across $n$ different elements from the set ($n\le m$). We do not care what are the numbers drawn, and halt once $n$ different numbers were seen during this process.

This is a variation of the [Coupon collector's problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coupon_collector%27s_problem), where one continues picking until seeing all $m$ elements of the set.

Example:

We draw numbers from the set $\{1,2,3,4,5\}$, $n=3$, $m=5$. The output
$\{1,5,2\}$ is produced by the following series of draws:

$1,1,5,1,5,2$

from the pool $\{1,2,3,4,5\}$. In this case, we halt after $6$ operations.

What is the expected time complexity of this algorithm?

Comment: Shouldn't the coupon's collector be `O(m*log(n))` instead of `O(n*log(n))`.

Comment: From an **intuitive** perspective: I don't think this problem is fundementally different from the collector's problem. Another remark: you say that you expect it to be *O(n)*, but what makes you think that it is independent from *m*?

Comment: Shankhunt42: I would expect this too! However, this page explains the complexity is `O(n log(n))`: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coupon_collector%27s_problem

Auberon: How can we reduce my problem to Collectors? I don't expect it to be `O(n)` but in between `O(n)` (best case scenario, all draws are unique right away) and `O(n log(n))` (Coupon's collector problem). Intuitively I would say the complexity is also dependent on `m`: the closer `n` and `m` are, the larger the complexity will grow.

Comment: @skankhunt42 In the collector's problem, there is only one input factor ( namely $n$ ). Where do you get $m$ from?

Comment: I edited the question, because I understood Coupon's collectors wrong. In that problem you have a set of `n` elements, where you must draw all elements with replacement. My problem is a variation, not a relaxation.

Comment: @MichielBorkent "(...) in between $O(n)$ and $O(n*log(n))$..." that doesn't make much sense, according to the defintion of big-oh. What you might want to say is that you suspect your problem to be $\Omega(n*log(n))$ **and** $O(log(n))$

Comment: @Auberon I no longer believe that, I understood Coupon's collector wrongly. Intuitively, the complexity has to be dependent on both `n` and `m`.

Comment: Auberon: I stand corrected.

Comment: Let us assume Wikipedia is correct (this isn't always the case!! Especially for complexity results. I've corrected those multiple times). Additionaly, let us say your assumption that **your** problem can be solved in $O(n)$ is correct. i.e. that means that you can solve your problem with an algorithm that runs in $O(n)$. But what if $m = n$ (i.e. the collector's problem)? It would mean that you've found an algorithm that solves the collector's problem in $O(n)$, which can't be true except if Wiki is incorrect or you've found a better algorithm (I doubt the latter).

Comment: @Auberon are you sure with $\Omega (n * \log(n))$ and $O(\log(n))$? $\Omega$ is the lower bound and $\mathcal O$ is upper.

Comment: @Evil Sorry. Somehow I thought $n*log(n) \in O(log(n))$ for a second. Also I meant to say $O(n)$ instead of $O(log(n))$, but your remark still holds.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

When $m$ is much larger than $n$, the expected number of trials is basically linear in $n$.  We can make this more precise, as shown below.

Let $T_n$ be the random variable which counts the number of trials up to seeing $n$ different elements, where the elements are picked uniformly at random from a set of size $m$.

You can write $T_n$ as the sum of geometric random variables

$$T_n=1+G\left(1-\frac{1}{m}\right)+G\left(1-\frac{2}{m}\right)+...+G\left(1-\frac{n-1}{m}\right)$$

where $G(p)$ is a geometric random variable with parameter $p$ (number of trails up  to the first success, where success happens with probability $p$ (I leave it to you to prove the equivalence).

Using linearity of expectation:

$$\begin{align*}
\mathbb{E}\left[T_n\right]&=\sum\limits_{i=0}^{n-1}\mathbb{E}\left[G\left(1-\frac{i}{m}\right)\right]\\
&=\sum\limits_{i=0}^{n-1}\frac{m}{m-i}\\
&=m\left(\frac{1}{m}+\frac{1}{m-1}+...+\frac{1}{m-n+1}\right)\\
&=m\left(H_m-H_{m-n}\right)
\end{align*}$$

where $H_k$ is the [harmonic sum](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Harmonic_series_(mathematics)), which satisfies $\frac{1}{2(k+1)}\le H_k-\ln k - \gamma\le \frac{1}{2k}$, where $\gamma$ is the [Euler–Mascheroni constant](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler%E2%80%93Mascheroni_constant) (see [Wolfram's](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/HarmonicNumber.html) page on harmonic numbers). Using these bounds for harmonic numbers we have:

$$\begin{align*}
\mathbb{E}\left[T_n\right]&\le m\left(\frac{1}{2m}+\ln m +\gamma -\left(\frac{1}{2(m-n+1)}+\ln(m-n)+\gamma\right)\right)\\
&\le m\left(\frac{1}{2m}+\ln\frac{m}{m-n}\right)=\frac{1}{2}+m\ln\frac{m}{m-n}.
\end{align*}$$

Note that $m\ln\frac{m}{m-n}=m\ln\left(1+\frac{n}{m-n}\right)\approx n$ when $n\ll m$, so for $m$ much larger than $n$, the expected number of trials is linear in $n$.